# Server render cannot get the nested route string

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, server-rendering

When I visit `/m/song`, the htmlstring only contains Layouts component

```
htmlstring = renderToString(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <StaticRouter location={ctx.url} context={context}>
            {renderRoutes(routesConfig)}
        </StaticRouter>
    </Provider>
);


const routesConfig = [{
    component: Layouts,
    routes:[{path: '/m/song', componentName: 'Song', component: Song}]
    …
```

The htmlstring should contanin both Layouts and Song components.

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the following in the render of your 'Layout' component? `{renderRoutes(routesConfig.routes)}`

As per documentation, 
[npmjs.com/package/react-router-config](https://npmjs.com/package/react-router-config), child routes ('Song' in your case) won't render without this line.